# Bootstrap Styling Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to preform the following but having the search button as a drop down?

```html
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButtons" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Options</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to have the search button ON a drop down? It's unclear as to what you're asking here.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will work for you...

```
<div class="input-append">
                  <input type="text">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                      Search
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                   <button class="btn" tabindex="-1">Options</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
```